Find a counterxample: is there anything better than a laplacian?
While studying the correspondence between maximum likelyhood estimation for a linear model with iid noise and norm approximation with penalty functions, I thought: $l_1$ is a cool penalty because it is the only convex function that is so little punishing towards outliers, and promoting sparsity. But then, why it had to be the Laplacian the associated noise?
The relationship between the associated penalty function and the distribution is given by
$$
\Phi(x) = - \log p(x).
$$
My answer was: well, between log-concave distributions (a necessary and sufficient condition for the above equivalence to hold, in convex optimization), it must be that one with the heaviest tails (recall it has a kurtosis, measure of "tailedness2, of 6).
Thus, here we go:
Is there any log-concave distribution with a strictly higher kurtosis than 6?
or if you want, is my answer correct to why Laplacian had to be the boundary of some set, with respect to kurtosis?
